# Evaluating fractional indices (negative)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When I want to evaluate $6^{-2/3}$, I get $0.30285\ldots$

The correct answer is $-10$.

Am I breaking any rules?

Comment: Where did you find such an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer seems correct.  There is no way you can take a positive number to an exponent and get a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$6^{-2/3}=\frac{1}{6^{2/3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{36}}$$